# Full screen does not work on a Youtube embedded video on my site when using chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, youtube

On my website, I embedded a Youtube video with this simple code:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/bpqTiwfzqdo" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

The results is the video that is at the bottom of the page here:
http://www.rpginsider.com/child-of-light-releases/

When in Chrome and I press the full screen button on that video, the video does not go full screen. Instead my whole browser goes full screen (as if I pressed F11) but not the video.

However, when I use Explorer or Firefox, full screen works just fine. So obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, have you ever found a solution to this? I am having the same problem. Thank you

Comment: Same here. But mine goes full screen for a sec and then goes back to how it was

Comment: @user3591728 did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

This issue can be caused by CSS Animations. If any of the iframe's ancestor elements is animated by CSS3 Animations with an (-webkit-)animation-fill-mode property set to "forwards" or "both", the video isn't set to fullscreen on Chrome.

Comment: removing the animations from the parent worked for me. Now I need the remove the animation after the iframe loads!

Answer (score 1):

try to remove

```
="allowfullscreen"
```

so past this one

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/bpqTiwfzqdo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I Checked your website , it's not the only video that don't offer fullscreen all your videos with chrome , I think the problem is with a wordpress plugin , try to disable livefyre and check

Comment: I disabled Livefyre and tried it again. Problem still exists. I also tried disabling "BJ Lazy Load" and "Featured Video" plugins. Still no help.

What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what is happening with my embed, fullscreen works fine in IE and Firefox but the video is being pulled up and to the left in Chrome because I have transform translate styling applied to the iframe which is affecting the video in fullscreen mode, but at the same time I also have a position absolute applied to the iframe with a top of 50% which is not affecting the iframe in fullscreen mode.

I'm going to listen for fullscreen changes on the iframe and remove the translate css on the iframe and add it back when going back to normal. [How can I detect when an iFrame goes fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389115/how-can-i-detect-when-an-iframe-goes-fullscreen)

---

World's not perfect, the fullscreen api is not playing well with me. Scraping that idea, removing the translate css altogether and going back to negative top and left margins half the iframe's dimensions. Fullscreen works fine in chrome that way.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. I had the same issue.

```
 <div class="blog-post blog-large fadeInLeft">
```

My youtube iframe was in a card and that card had an css animation. Deleting that animation (fadeInLeft) solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with css:

```
embed,
iframe,
object {
max-width: 100%!important;
    max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. I have just faced exactly the same issue in 2021 on **Safari**. The full screen button on the Youtube iframe will make the whole web page display full screen instead of the actual video. The problem was also related to CSS animation being applied to the parent element of the iframe so removing animation solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not only CSS animations can cause this. For me it also happened when using a `clip-path` on one of the ancestors.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34194226)