# How can I detect when an iFrame goes fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, iframe

I have a document that is embedded in my site by using an iFrame. The iFrame is from Box.com document viewer. The iFrame has its own built in fullscreen button. The fullscreen button is within the iFrame so I cannot attach a click event listener to the button. I added the attribute allowfullscreen to the iFrame to allow it to go fullscreen.

I want to do something like this:

```
$('iframe').on 'EnterFullScreen', () ->
  # Run function
```

But what event do I have to listen to, to detect when the iFrame is going fullscreen?

Here is a jsfiddle with the type of document I am embedding. The goal is to detect when the document goes fullscreen.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rnvcm

Comment: Can you not just attach an event to the fullscreen button?

$("#goFullScreen").click(function(){......});

Comment: The fullscreen button is within the iframe! I can't attach event listeners to buttons within the iFrame I tried.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Yah here it is. The goal is to detect when the iframe goes fullscreen. http://jsfiddle.net/Rnvcm/

Comment: Except it looks like it does not actually allow the document to go fullscreen in jsfiddle

Comment: Is the domain in the iframe yours?

Comment: no it is the example document on the box webpage, the service we use to embed documents.

Comment: Is this iframe a requirement? It may be a better option to create your own full-screen mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can listen for a fullscreen change in your parent page (the one having the `iframe`):

```
function changeHandler(e) {
   // Mode has changed.
}

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the events pointed out by **putvande** you can still bind your own `enterFullScreen` event:

```
$(document).on('fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange msfullscreenchange', function() {
    if (document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement)
    {
        $(document).trigger('enterFullScreen');
    }
    else
    {
        $(document).trigger('leaveFullScreen');
    }
});
```

You can use the simpler `enterFullScreen` event now using:

```
$(document).on('enterFullScreen', function(){
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: This is really helpful in addition to putvande's answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me exactly as described in a Cordova 4.0.0 (Android 4.1.1) app running on a Galaxy S4 (5.0.1 Lollipop) but the following does:

```
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
  if (document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
    if (window.screen && typeof window.screen.unlockOrientation === 'function') {
      window.screen.unlockOrientation(); // Unlock screen orientation
    }
  } else {
    if (window.screen && typeof window.screen.lockOrientation === 'function') {
      window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait-primary'); // Relock screen orientation
    }
  }
});
```

I am using the Cordova ScreenOrientation plugin to handle orientation locking based on fullscreen detection.